# Values are not inserting while paging is given in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using the grid view with paging.I want to insert only the selected check box value in database.multiple value is selecting but value is not inserting in database.I have tried out with below code.help me out from these problem

**ASPX CODE**

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvsubject" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns = "false" CssClass="mGrid1"  AllowPaging ="true" OnPageIndexChanging="gvsubject_PageIndexChanging" OnRowDataBound="gvsubject_RowDataBound">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="subject" HeaderText="subject" SortExpression="subject"/>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select">
            <HeaderTemplate>
            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkAll" runat="server" onclick = "checkAll(this);" />
             </HeaderTemplate> 
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="chk" runat="server" onclick = "checkAll(this);"/>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" onclick = "Check_Click(this)"/>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

**CODE File**

```
         ArrayList CheckBoxArray;
         if (ViewState["CheckBoxArray"] != null)
         {
             CheckBoxArray = (ArrayList)ViewState["CheckBoxArray"];
         }
         else
         {
             CheckBoxArray = new ArrayList();
         }

         if (IsPostBack)
         {
             int CheckBoxIndex;
             bool CheckAllWasChecked = false;
             CheckBox chkAll = (CheckBox)gvsubject.HeaderRow.Cells[0].FindControl("chkAll");
             string checkAllIndex = "chkAll-" + gvsubject.PageIndex;
             if (chkAll.Checked)
             {
                 if (CheckBoxArray.IndexOf(checkAllIndex) == -1)
                 {
                     CheckBoxArray.Add(checkAllIndex);
                 }
             }
             else
             {
                 if (CheckBoxArray.IndexOf(checkAllIndex) != -1)
                 {
                     CheckBoxArray.Remove(checkAllIndex);
                     CheckAllWasChecked = true;
                 }
             }
             for (int i = 0; i < gvsubject.Rows.Count; i++)
             {
                 if (gvsubject.Rows[i].RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
                 {
                     CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)gvsubject.Rows[i].Cells[0].FindControl("CheckBox1");
                     CheckBoxIndex = gvsubject.PageSize * gvsubject.PageIndex + (i + 1);
                     if (chk.Checked)
                     {
                         if (CheckBoxArray.IndexOf(CheckBoxIndex) == -1 && !CheckAllWasChecked)
                         {
                             CheckBoxArray.Add(CheckBoxIndex);
                         }
                     }
                     else
                     {
                         if (CheckBoxArray.IndexOf(CheckBoxIndex) != -1 || CheckAllWasChecked)
                         {
                             CheckBoxArray.Remove(CheckBoxIndex);
                         }
                     }
                 }
             }
         }
         ViewState["CheckBoxArray"] = CheckBoxArray;
         gvsubject.DataSource = dt;
         gvsubject.DataBind();
    }

protected void btnno_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string semester = ddlsemester.SelectedValue;
        string section = txtsection.Text;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
       foreach (GridViewRow gv in gvsubject.Rows)
        {
            if (gv.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                CheckBox chk = (gv.Cells[0].FindControl("CheckBox1") as CheckBox);
                if (chk.Checked)
                {
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into tblassignsub(semester,section,subject,academicyear) values (@semester,@section,@subject,@academicyear)");
                    con.Open();
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@semester", ddlsemester.SelectedValue);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@section", txtsection.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@subject", gv.Cells[0].Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@academicyear", txtacdyear.Text);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    con.Close();
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: I dont see connection string in your `SqlCommand`

Comment: see in the button click

Comment: Sqlcommand should be `SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(
            your query, con);`

Comment: Yes, missed connection in sqllcommand,

Comment: SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into tblassignsub(semester,section,subject,academicyear) values (@semester,@section,@subject,@academicyear)", con);

Comment: i have added but same nothing is adding in database

Comment: Use debugger and let us know what error you are facing..

Comment: without paging same query is working but with paging these one is not working

Answer (score 0):

You have missesd connection string in SqlCommand

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into tblassignsub(semester,section,subject,academicyear) values (@semester,@section,@subject,@academicyear)");
```

Try this

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into tblassignsub(semester,section,subject,academicyear) values (@semester,@section,@subject,@academicyear)",con);
```

Comment: @RavintherM not working is not sufficient to identify your exact prob..use debugger in button click and check what error occurred